# How to see which jdbc driver is missing when "No suitable driver" happens in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc

I am running Spark locally against a remote SQL Server database using pyspark. The jars that I *think* are needed are already copied to the `$SPARK_HOME/jars` directory.  In addition they are included as `spark.jars.packages` as such:

```py
    spark_session = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("AzsqlSparkApplication") \
        .master("local[2]") \
        .config('spark.jars.packages',
com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0,"
                "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.3,org.apache.spark) \
        .getOrCreate()
```

However the following error occurs in the spark `Driver` program:

```java
 java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$2(JDBCOptions.scala:109)
```

The specific `jdbc` class attempted to load is however not printed. How can that info be obtained?

Comment: The code calls `DriverManager.getDriver(String)`, which accepts a JDBC URL. It means that there is no registered driver for the URL you specified.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Yes in a way but the `com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0` package contains that class

Comment: I don't think spark-mssql-connector is a JDBC driver, as far as I can tell from it [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver16), it is a different way of connecting. If you want to connect with JDBC, you need the [mssql-jdbc driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc).